# one session per user spring security 3.2

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

i want limit one session per one user and i follow the next steps.
web.xml

```
<listener>
<listener-class>
  org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
 <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/pages/comun/index.xhtml"
        session-fixation-protection="none">
        <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            expired-url="/pages/comun/index.xhtml" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
    </sec:session-management>
```

can not be done, someone to help me appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` in your `web.xml`.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This adds session data to the `SessionRegistry` created by your `spring-security.xml`.